# Android browser not reading variable in PHP session

Tags: php, android, session, mobile, session-variables

I have a PHP session script that works fine on all browsers, except Android mobile - it also works fine in Android browser if you view the desktop site. It is the same for both Chrome and MS Edge on Android.

The PHP script is a content switcher based on geo and/or slug info. I am not going to post the entire script here; it all works fine.

Here is the relevant bit from the homepage:

```
<?php session_start();

... bunch of stuff that produces an $n value ...

echo 'we have a content number here: ' . $n;

$_SESSION['content_number'] = $n;
}
```

The correct content number is echoed in all platforms, including the Android mobile browsers. The next pages should easily pick up the $n value with this:

```
<?php session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['content_number'])){
    $n = $_SESSION['content_number'];
} else {
    ... cms specific homepage redirect ...; 
};
```

That works as expected in all browsers, but in Android mobile browser the other pages redirect to the homepage. The session content number is not recognized for some reason.

When I remove the if else condition from the next pages and just try to echo either `$_SESSION['content_number']` or `$n`, nothing is found.

When I hardcode an $n value in the home page script - like `$n = '2';` - the Android mobile browser does open the next page with the correct content:

```
<?php session_start();

$n = '2';

$_SESSION['content_number'] = $n;
}
```

Useless, but that works fine. Apparently there is nothing wrong with the sessions mechanism, cookies, etc.!

Without the if else condition in the next pages, with `$n = '2';` on the homepage, echoing the session content number also works fine. The PHP session works.

What could be the reason that Android mobile can't read $n when all the other browsers can?

Are there any known issues with PHP sessions on Android mobile that I should take into consideration?

Are there other ways to set the session variable? I have tried to sanitize and process $n, but haven't found anything that makes a difference.

What else could I try to troubleshoot this? I am running out of ideas.

Edit:

var_dump of the next page on Android:

```
array(3) { ["Session"]=> array(0) { } ["ProcessWire1"]=> array(1) { ["SessionHandlerDB"]=> array(1) { ["ts"]=> int(1595783349) } } ["content_number"]=> NULL }
```

var_dump of the next page on other browsers:

```
array(3) { ["Session"]=> array(0) { } ["ProcessWire1"]=> array(1) { ["SessionHandlerDB"]=> array(1) { ["ts"]=> int(1595783260) } } ["content_number"]=> int(1) }
```

Comment: If everything works as expected on Android when you hard-code `$n = 2` at the opening page... but not when `$n = { bunch of stuff that produces an $n value }` ... the behavior of your remaining pages only makes sense if `$n = NULL`. See what `var_dump($_SESSION)` shows on Android.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Markus AO. This is the var_dump on Android:

array(3) { ["Session"]=> array(0) { } ["ProcessWire1"]=> array(1) { ["SessionHandlerDB"]=> array(1) { ["ts"]=> int(1595783349) } } ["summit_number"]=> NULL }

/// but this is the var_dump on other browsers: 

array(3) { ["Session"]=> array(0) { } ["ProcessWire1"]=> array(1) { ["SessionHandlerDB"]=> array(1) { ["ts"]=> int(1595783260) } } ["summit_number"]=> int(1) }

Comment: As suspected, `["summit_number"]=> NULL`. I presume you also get `NULL` even if you `var_dump` on the page where this session variable is initially set. Please update the OP with your code for "*bunch of stuff that produces an $n value*", I suspect there are clues there as to what's actually going on.

Comment: @Markus AO, see above. There is nothing wrong with the "bunch of stuff that produces an $n value". See the var_dump in all other browser and see above with latest additions. There is a valid $n value, as I had confirmed several ways - and I already knew the session var was NULL in Android, so you weren't really telling anything new there.

Comment: Can you confirm whether `$_SESSION['content_number']` is `NULL` or not with Android on the page where you create `$n` and set it? `var_dump` on the first page. Thing here is, a browser has nothing to do with PHP session data or other variables under the hood, aside providing a cookie with the session ID, unless there's particular input from the browser that impacts your program flow. ... Now, to clarify, you're defining `content_number`, however later you reference `summit_number`?
... Probably a good idea to make a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to see what bugs.

Comment: content_number is set on the homepage, visible on Android mobile as well. $n is absolutely set and the value gets passed to other pages on all other browsers with no problem. I can't figure out why it is NULL in Android - unless I hard-code it. And it is summit_number all the way through in my code; I was trying to make the examples more generic. Ignore that.

Comment: Please `var_dump($_SESSION)` on the first page to ensure that the generated `$n` is actually saved into `$_SESSION` on Android instances to begin with. In any case, **if hard-coded `$n = 2;` is properly stored for Android sessions, but generated `$n` is not**, the only coherent explanation is that there's something peculiar with the generated `$n` value that causes your fluke with Android. A MCVE you can share here would make this heaps easier for others to debug.

Comment: Thanks. Generated $n shows up correctly on Android mobile in the first page, both in echo $n and in ["content_number"]=> int(2) - or int(1) or whatever generated $n is. // after minor changes in "bunch of stuff", I now no longer get ["content_number"]=> NULL on the next pages on Android; it is now stuck on ["content_number"]=> int(1) - still working fine on all other browsers. I had already disabled caching as much as possible. Is the problem in how the session cookie is stored on Android?

Comment: Humor yourself and have the pages `echo SID;`, see if it remains constant or changes, ie. if you're still using the same session or not. Yes it's possible that there's a glitch with the Android browser cookie handling. Have you tried this with another phone and the same browser, to eliminate it's not unique to your device's installation / its configuration? Browser version would be relevant information for others troubleshooting this.

Comment: Thanks again Markus AO. With echo session_id(), the session is constant across pages, on both Android and other browsers. Android ignores the change of the variable in the session - except for one glorious moment after I had added these echoes when it suddenly did pick up the change, but only once (wtf??). Testing on Android emulators in Genymotion confirms it is not only a glitch on my mobile. Is there a way to make extra sure a variable is added to a session?

Comment: If the session ID remains constant, sessions/cookies are handled fine on Android. Since session variable setting and reading has nothing to do with the browser (the browser's only job is to pass the cookie/SID), something here doesn't add up. Next step in debugging: [**Create a MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that replicates the problem, then share it here so others can verify and test possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), by eliminating elements, I found "the cause" of my problem. This innocuous piece of CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 767px){#bg{background:url("../video/video.png") center center/cover no-repeat}#bg video{display:none}}
```

This is a piece from a compacted CSS file produced from SASS by Koala.

Deleting it from my style.css file fixes the problem; Android can suddenly read the correct variable from the session without issues.

The problem also disappears when I use a standard formatted version of that bit of CSS instead of this compacted version.

Why this causes Android not to read the latest variable from the session, I have no clue. It makes absolutely no sense to me. Any ideas?

The problem probably never was specifically with Android, but with mobile in general, considering the media query targets mobile. I have not tested anything on iPhone - don't have access to one at the moment.

But I don't understand how a CSS mistake can cause a problem with sessions.